# Selecting elements based on multiple conditions in attributes in XPATH

Tags: xpath

I want to select Value attribute of Term Element based on value of another attribute of Term Element. Please see the XML input of XPath here.

```
<Term Value="1025" Name="dnumber"/>
<Term Value="House" Name="adrtype"/>
<Term Value="My Address line 1" Name="adrline1"/>
<Term Value="My Address line 2" Name="adrline3"/>
<Term Value="12345" Name="adrpstcode"/>
<Term Value="07" Name="adrareacod"/>
<Term Value="123456789" Name="adrphone"/>
<Term Value="987654321" Name="adrmobile"/>
<Term Value="PARENT" Name="adrcntrel"/>
```

for e.g. here i want to select value "My Address line 1" where Name is "adrline1" if Name "adrtype" has value "House" and if any other values then do not.

and I am trying XPath Exression as below.

```
"/Term[@Name='adrtype' and @Value='House']/Term[@Name='adrline1' ]/@Value"
```

but I am not getting any value.

Comment: i think you are missing some xml structure? beacause in XPath you are taking `Term[@Name='adrline1' ]/@Value` which is child of `/Term[@Name='adrtype' and @Value='House']`.

Comment: I know the Xpath which I am using is not correct and structure before Term Element doesnt matter as xpath expression will be coming down to selecting attributes of Term element only

Comment: The relation between Term to Term is sibling not parent to child... see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the XML structure is same as given input then your XPath shoud be change like:

```
//Term[@Name='adrtype' and @Value='House']/following-sibling::Term[@Name='adrline1']/@Value
```

See this: http://xsltransform.net/jxWYjVB

Comment: Thanks a lot for reference.I got it by using preceeding-sibling and then selecting the value which I want to select.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that your XML needs a bit of structuring, like this;

```
<Terms>
       <Term Value="1025" Name="dnumber"/>
       <Term Value="House" Name="adrtype"/>
       <Term Value="My Address line 1" Name="adrline1"/>
       <Term Value="My Address line 2" Name="adrline3"/>
       <Term Value="12345" Name="adrpstcode"/>
       <Term Value="07" Name="adrareacod"/>
       <Term Value="123456789" Name="adrphone"/>
       <Term Value="987654321" Name="adrmobile"/>
       <Term Value="PARENT" Name="adrcntrel"/>
</Terms>
```

After that, you can use this to locate and get the value. Remember to use `|` operator it is handy in this kind of situations. Also using an XPath tester like [this](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) can help you to save time in the future.

```
(//Term[@Name='adrline1' ]/@Value | //Term[@Name='adrtype' and @Value='House'] )[2]
```